# My app hangs forever after attaching cordova-2.3.0.js

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I made the following steps to use Phonegap library with my app:

1. download phohegap-2.3.0 from http://phonegap.com/download/
2. copy cordova-2.3.0.js from phonegap-2.3.0/lib/android/ to the root
   directory of my **sencha touch 2** application
3. add the following to **app.json** in the root directory of my sencha
   touch app:

   ```
       {   
           "path": "cordova-2.3.0.js",
           "update": "delta"
       },
   ```

In the Chrome browser it works OK. But when I run the app on a real device (Android 2.3.0) it hangs forever on the first standart blinking screen.

Does anyone know - **have I made all required steps** to install Phonegap or there are some more ones?

**Update**

I had generated an empty application and it did not work with attached cordova.js (when the object was before attached sencha-touch.js).

It may be strange but the application loads normally when I place the strings with "cordova-...js" on the bottom of a "js" field (previously it was the first object in the "js" array):

```
"js": [
        {
            "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js"
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
            "update": "delta"
        },
        {
            "path": "cordova-2.2.0.js"
        }
    ]...
```

However I am not sure that PhoneGap works properly. I will test it and will publish my result.

Comment: looks to me like you did follow the steps correctly. Try removing "update" : "delta" to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @cclerville Thank you. Have you experience of attaching cordova.js or you just think so?

Comment: @cclerville Please see my update. Have you any explanation for it?

Comment: I have used cordova.2.2.0.js before. I wrote a blog post on packaging a sencha touch app recently with cordova. Here is the link: http://cclerville.blogspot.com/2013/01/sencha-touch-21-phonegap-220-android_3.html .

Comment: @cclerville Thank you, I noticed your link earlier. I did the steps. But if I do "sencha app build native" instead of "sencha app build native" to build apk, it seems html panels don't not work. And buttons on 'hbox' layout don't work too. It seems like some components is not included.

Comment: @cclerville  If I do 'sencha --debug package build config.json' it builds normally but I don't know how to attach cordova lib correctly.

Comment: @cclerville It seems not enough to attach cordova.js. Probably we must attach some jar or other files. As I don't understand the reason clearly, so, I try to do the described steps. Now I build the app: "sencha app build testing" to view the js in a browser in non-minify mode.

Comment: @cclerville I do not understand where (a build process) we acess the cordova-2.2.0.jar. I suppose the file or it's part is packed to apk. We must use the information, mustn't we? I decompile the apk, but I don't it.

Comment: try running "sencha package build config.json".

Comment: @cclerville BTW, in your tutorial you forgot to mention about correct packager.json file. If a user does not edit it then it probably will not work for android, because there are required fields: 'androidAPILevel', 'sdkPath' and 'certificationPath'.

Comment: @cclerville I did not mention the step about placing cordova.x.x.jar n your tutorial (please see http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/, the section "Set up PhoneGap")